# Erro ao inserir Dados no Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, query

Tenho essa query para inserir um dado no banco:

```
INSERT INTO `bancoTeste`.`TabelaTeste` (`t_id`,`t_label`, `t_parametro`, `t_valor`, `t_descricao`, `t_valores_padrao`, `t_tipo`) 
VALUES ('NULL','Cargas', 'monitorar_carga','N', 'apresentar as cargas dos veículos do grupo de monitoramento','sim_ou_nao', 'combo');
```

**Erro do mysql**

> 1 row(s) affected, 1 warning(s): 1366 Incorrect integer value: 'NULL'
>   for column 'sis00_id' at row 1

Como proceder ?

Comment: vc quer inserir o valor NULL no campo t_id ok? se for isso melhor que seja '0' não? ou o campo não está INT?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Retire as aspas de `'NULL'`, caso contrário ela será uma string incompatível com o tipo de valor da coluna `t_id` da tabela.

Com `'NULL'` (entre aspas), irá inserir o registro na tabela, conforme a mensagem:

> 1 row(s) affected

Porém irá gerar o alerta:

> 1 warning(s)

Da forma abaixo, o alerta não será gerado:

```
INSERT INTO `bancoTeste`.`TabelaTeste` (`t_id`,`t_label`, `t_parametro`, `t_valor`, `t_descricao`, `t_valores_padrao`, `t_tipo`) 
VALUES (NULL,'Cargas', 'monitorar_carga','N', 'apresentar as cargas dos veículos do grupo de monitoramento','sim_ou_nao', 'combo');
```

Mas, se a coluna `t_id` for a `primary-key auto_increment`, basta omiti-la:

```
INSERT INTO `bancoTeste`.`TabelaTeste` (`t_label`, `t_parametro`, `t_valor`, `t_descricao`, `t_valores_padrao`, `t_tipo`) 
VALUES ('Cargas', 'monitorar_carga','N', 'apresentar as cargas dos veículos do grupo de monitoramento','sim_ou_nao', 'combo');
```

Answer (score 0):

Basta você retirar o t_id da sql. No seu banco de dados esse campo está configurado como auto_increment? Caso esteja basta retirar o mesmo. A sql ficaria da seguinte forma:

```
INSERT INTO `bancoTeste`.`TabelaTeste` (`t_label`, `t_parametro`, `t_valor`, `t_descricao`, `t_valores_padrao`, `t_tipo`) VALUES ('Cargas', 'monitorar_carga','N', 'apresentar as cargas dos veículos do grupo de monitoramento','sim_ou_nao', 'combo');
```